# e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: intcannot be converted to an Element

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kapt

I am trying to implement Room in my android application. I am trying to get data from API and save them in local database. But when I run the application this error occurred

> e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> intcannot be converted to an Element

This is my database class:

```
@Database(entities = [
    (User::class)],
        version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class UserDatabase : RoomDatabase() {


    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: UserDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): UserDatabase {

            if (INSTANCE == null){
                synchronized(this){
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context.applicationContext,
                            UserDatabase::class.java,
                            "user_database")
                            .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }


}
```

This is my Repository:

```
class Repository(application: Application) {


    private var mUserDao: UserDao

init {
        val db = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application)


    }
    @WorkerThread
    fun createUser(user: User) {
        mUserDao.createUser(user)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    fun deleteUser(id: Int) {
        mUserDao.deleteUser(id)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    fun getUser(id: Int) {
        mUserDao.getUser(id)
    }
```

And here is my userDao

```
@Dao
interface UserDao{

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun createUser(user: User)

    @Delete
    fun deleteUser(int: Int)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = :userID")
    fun getUser(userID: Int): LiveData<User>

}
```

My LogginViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    var repository: Repository = Repository(application)


    fun createUser(user: User) = repository.createUser(user)

}
```

Also this error get occurred:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
> ':app:kaptDebugKotlin' <30 internal calls> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)<1
> internal call>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more
> details   at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:16)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithKotlincTask.compile(KaptWithKotlincTask.kt:79)<17
> internal calls> ...33 more

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies in your `@Delete`

```
@Delete
fun deleteUser(int: Int)
```

Which should be

```
@Delete
fun deleteUser(user: User)
```

The parameter for `@Delete` method should be an entity or an array of an entity, not an `Int`

Comment: it shows me this error: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Comment: I execute the method when I make a network call using retrofit. call.enqueue of retrofit gets executed in background. I don't understand

Comment: @Jona that's a different question. If it solved your original question, accept it as an answer and you are free to post another question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Thanks.This was my first time implementing Room via MVVM, saved 2 days of chaos

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution:

As @musooff mentioned above I changed the delete method like this:

```
@Delete
fun deleteUser(user: User)
```

or if you want to delete a user with a specific id you do this query:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = :id")
fun deleteUser(id: Int)
```

Then to solve next error you should execute methods in UserDao inside an Asynctask
in Repository file for example for creating user I did this:

```
private class insertAsyncTask internal constructor(private val mAsyncTaskDao: UserDao) : AsyncTask<User, Void, Void>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: User): Void? {
        mAsyncTaskDao.createUser(params[0])
        return null
    }
}
```

Then createUser function in Repository goes like this:

```
fun createUser(user: User) {
    insertAsyncTask(mUserDao).execute(user)
}
```

This solved the problem for me.